# socket send and receive fail only first time

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

So I made this program to make a socket connection between a server and a client (udp), for the client to send a string and the server to receive that string and send it back with the word "Back" included.
I works well, the problem is it just doesn't work the first time I run it. The client doesn't print the echoed string I almost sure that it doesn't receive the first time I run.

However, when I end the program and run it again with the same commands it works and keep working after that everytime I run it, and echo everything back as it suppose to.
Here are the client and the server sending and receiving code lines.

client side:

```
len = sendto (s,string,strlen(string),0,(struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof (servAddr));
// Recieve echo string
recvfrom (s,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,NULL,NULL);
buffer[len+5] = '\0';
// Print and verify echoed string
fputs(buffer,stdout);
```

server side:

```
len =    recvfrom (s,buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);

    buffer[len]   =' ';
    buffer[len+1] ='B';
    buffer[len+2] ='a';
    buffer[len+3] ='c';
    buffer[len+4] ='k';
    buffer[len+5] = '\0';
      // Send String
    sendto (s,buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr));
```

binding and everything is working correctly.
Why does it fail the first time only?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `clntAddrLen` initialized before calling `recvfrom` in the server ? It needs to be.

Comment: Put some proper error handling into your code and report the results here. You aren't even checking for end of stream, let alone errors. Don't write code like this.

Comment: "I almost sure that it doesn't receive the first time I run" What do you base this statement on?

Comment: Show us how you are initializing address structures .. also please add error checks on sendto, recvfrom